# ASP.NET MVC registration form change according to dropdownlist selection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement a registration form that changes according to the `@Html.DropDownListFor()` selections. For example, the dropdownlist consists of several selections such as:

- Admin
- Student

If I select Admin, the registration page will display the Admin registration form and selecting Student will have the view to display the Student registration form. By pressing the Submit button, the data in the selected registration form will be posted to the POST method in the controller.

How do I implement this? Do I really need to use JavaScript to do so?

**UPDATE:**

I've done the view as following codes and used the `@Html.BeginForm()` & `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="container" style="width:40%; margin-top:3%">
    -- the button --
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AdminModal">Register Admin Account</a>

    <div class="modal fade" id="AdminModal" style="width:auto">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                    <h3 class="modal-title" >Admin Modal</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form id="AdminForm">
    -- with other textfields ---
    -- And DropDownList for selecting User role --

                    </form>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
                    <input type="reset" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSubmit" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    }
```

And the second `div`, which also same with the **code snippet** above by using the `dialog form` included in one `div`. 
Meaning that in one `Html.BeginForm()`, I have a lot of **submit** `button`.

How can I choose which form to submit when clicking the **submit** button and `POST` it with validation as well?

Any approach will be much appreciate.  Thanks !

Comment: Yes in some way or another this will involve JS. Anytime you want front-end changes to occur without the browser refreshing, you'll use JS.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to look into jQuery.  It will let you write code like

```
$("#drop").change(function () {
    // operations to update form.
});
```

If you want any of dynamically generated controls to be populated, based on your user inputs, you might want to look into jQuery AJAX.

jQuery does simplify a lot of the work that would have needed to be done with vanilla JavaScript.